# Jade / Pug: Hide div unless variable has data

Tags: javascript, pug

I want to hide a div unless the div has received data to the local variable. I have this at the moment:

```
    div#cost
      p You earn #{cost} a day!
```

But it displays on the page. How do I hide it until it receives the data? Im confused about Jade's if/else syntax

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
-if (cost)
    div#cost
        p You earn #{cost} a day!
```

First of all, the `-` means that it is *unbuffered* Javascript code. Meaning this will not get rendered in the final version of the template. If you would want that, you should use a script tag like so: `script.`.

Second, the if-statement will check if cost is not equal to null or undefined. When it doesn't exists, the code inside the if-statement will be skipped.

The above code will result in the following HTML if cost is not equal to null or undefined:

```
<div id="cost">
    <p>You earn ... cost a day!</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve is not possible.
jade/pug is a template engine, you can give placeholder variable, perform loops, conditions etc but your browser does not understand jade/pug it understands only HTML, which means your template will be converted to a static HTML content before being displayed.

The if/else block decide what is going to be part of the generated HTML file, once the file is generated jade/pug does not have any control over it.

If you want to dynamically control your DOM you can use a web framework such as Angular, Vue, React or you can do DOM manipulation using jQuery or by hand with regular Javascript.

Comment: You can indeed interpret this question two ways. I gave the answer to the question of the variables being present in the templating engine (either being defined locally by unbuffered Javascript or fetched by Node.js), but this answer is very valid as well.